# Twitter Feed on IE, Opera, Safari

Tags: html, twitter

I have a page in which I've implemented the Twitter feed widget. If works nicely on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE, Opera, and Safari, it just comes up with "Tweets by @JackSchaible" and not the actual feed itself. Someone please help?

The url is www.logicanddesign.ca

Alternatively, here's my source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Logic & Design: Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/divs.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/fonts.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/tags.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/images.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Icon-OR.png" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/animations.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/socialMediaPlugins.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <img id="logo" alt="logo" src="images/Logo.png" />
            </header>
            <div id="divider">
                <img id="headerDivider" alt="Line" src="images/Line.jpg" />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <div class="Button" id="selectedButton">
                    <img id="arrowOverlay" alt="Overlay" src="images/Arrows/FadeArrow.png" />
                    <img id="extender" alt="Home" src="Images/Arrows/Arrow%20Body.png" />
                    <img id="selectedArrow" alt="Home" src="Images/Arrows/Home/Home.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="Button" id="aboutButton">
                    <img alt="About Me" src="Images/Arrows/About/About.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="Button" id="abilitiesButton">
                    <img alt="My Abilities" src="Images/Arrows/Abilities/Abilities.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="Button" id="portfolioButton">
                    <img alt="My Portfolio" src="Images/Arrows/Portfolio/Portfolio.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="Button" id="contactButton">
                    <img alt="Contact Me" src="Images/Arrows/Contact/Contact.png"/>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="mainContent">
                <div id="innerContent">
                    <p>Welcome to Logic & Design! If you are looking for work done and it has anything to do with a computer, you have come to the right place! My name is Jack Schaible and I do nearly everything computer-related. Whether it is software analysis, design, web apps, database design, web design or development, whatever your needs, I can fill them. I will take care of the technical side of things so you can focus on what matters: running your business!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="imageBar">
                    <div id="networkingIcons">
                        <div id="fb" class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/logicanddesign" data-width="200" data-height="75" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/JackSchaible" data-widget-id="266804071627898880">Tweets by @JackSchaible</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                    <div class="g-plus" data-width="199" data-height="69" data-href="https://plus.google.com/105579960548041650339" data-rel="author" data-theme="dark"></div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                      (function() {
                        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                      })();
                    </script>
                    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right"></script>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <script type="text/javascript">document.write((new Date).getFullYear());</script> Jack Schaible</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on all of my browsers when it is accessed form a server `http://localhost/twitter.html` or `http://www.logicanddesign.ca/` but not when viewed as html file: `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/twitter.html`. This seems to be a nuance of the .js script.

Comment: The js script came with the widget as a part of the code I was supposed to copy paste. I don't understand what's wrong with it.